# writeout collapses with pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

```
% Density Show Test
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
  \pgfmathparse{"\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}"}%
\else%
   \pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? "?" : "\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{#2}"}% 
\fi}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}\pgfmathresult
```

I have a pgfmathdeclarefunction `DensityShowTest`, that tests whether the `\Phase` is equal to 'gas', then the value `\Density` has to be multiplicated by 1000 (else not).

If the  \Phase equal to 'unknown', the \Density is equal to '-1' (which means unknown as well).

And the value of the Density (if not "?") has to be rounded to 2 digits (in all cases); which seems to be problematic.

The problem I have is, that I cannot write out that function; it must have something to do with the part `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}`

[image]

*Comment: Everything would be much easier if TikZ had an arithmetic rounding function, but the rounded version of a number has to be reserved for the written output at TikZ...*

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
Z;     Symbol;     Phase;     Density;    EXPECTED OUTPUT
1;     H;             gas;     0.0000899; 0.09
3;     Li;             solid;  0.53;      0.53 
118; Og;           unknown;  -1;          ?
}{\psetable}

% Density Show Test
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
  \pgfmathparse{"\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}"}%
\else%
   \pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? "?" : "\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{#2}"}% 
\fi}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}\pgfmathresult 

\def\Filename{densityshowtest.txt}
\newwrite\MyPSE
\immediate\openout\MyPSE=\Filename

\begin{document}
\foreach \row in {0,...,2}{%%
% In:   
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Z{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Symbol{\pgfplotsretval}
%% Phase
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Phase}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Phase{\pgfplotsretval}
% Density Test
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Density}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Density{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\DensityShowTest{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}
% OUT:
% This works:
\noindent \Z;~~~\Symbol;~~\Density; ~~\Phase; ~~\DensityShowTest \\
%
%  Problem here  =======================
%
% This works not: ======================
%\immediate\write\MyPSE{\Z; \Symbol; \Density; \Phase; \DensityShowTest}
}%%
\immediate\closeout\MyPSE

% So this does not work too: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true,]{\Filename}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Code passed through `\write` must be fully expandable to be fully expanded. I'd guess that `\pgfmathprintnumber` isn't expandable.

Comment: So I have to use: `\fpeval{round(#2,2)}`

Comment: No, but you have to change your `DensityShowTest` function (it can't work the way you're using it).

Comment: “Everything would be much easier if TikZ had an arithmetic rounding function” There is a `round` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to eagerly format the result within the function using `\pgfmathprintnumberto`. Note that this is really not how these functions should be used.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
Z;     Symbol;     Phase;     Density
1;     H;             gas;          0.0000899
3;     Li;             solid;        0.53
118; Og;           unknown;  -1
}{\psetable}

% Density Show Test
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{gas}=0
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed, precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathresult}%
\else%
  \pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? "\unexpanded{\def\pgfmathresult{?}}" : "\unexpanded{\pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed, precision=2]{#2}{\pgfmathresult}}"}%
  \pgfmathresult % evaluate the result to perform formatting
\fi
}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}\pgfmathresult 

\def\Filename{densityshowtest.txt}
\newwrite\MyPSE
\immediate\openout\MyPSE=\Filename

\begin{document}
\foreach \row in {0,...,2}{%%
% In:   
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Z{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Symbol{\pgfplotsretval}
%% Phase
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Phase}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\Phase{\pgfplotsretval}
% Density Test
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Density}\of{\psetable}%
\xdef\Density{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}%
\xdef\DensityShowTest{\pgfmathresult}%
% OUT:
% This works:
\noindent \Z;~~~\Symbol;~~\Density; ~~\Phase; ~~\DensityShowTest \\
%
%  Problem here  =======================
%
%  This works not: ======================
\immediate\write\MyPSE{\Z; \Symbol; \Density; \Phase; \DensityShowTest}
}%%
\immediate\closeout\MyPSE

% So this does not work too: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true,]{\Filename}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha. But there seems to be a mistake in the first decision, the output at gas should here be 0.09 (not 0). I had have said the values.

Comment: See the new colum 'EXPECTED OUTPUT' too.

Comment: In fact: it doesn't work that way.
With the first `\pgfmathprintnumberto` he rounds the initial value, not the value `1000*#2`.

Comment: @cis To be honest, I have no idea what this is supposed to do at all. For example what do you expect the result of `dim("#1")` to be? You know that `dim` will only work for arrays? Yet you are passing a string so the result will probably be 0 all the time.

Comment: Maybe a strange method with that dim, but dim("gas") = 3 and this is the one and only case, so this part works for me.

Comment: PS: There are 4 cases for dim("\Phase"): gas, solid, liquid and unknown. So this part should not be the problem; the rounding is the problem.

Comment: @cis With the latest PGF `\pgfmathprint{dim("gas")}` will print 1. This is the case since https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/1b7e3ddef23414ff660e269adb0c12d26c152bb6. Before that `dim` was undocumented.

Comment: I see at the editor https://texwelt.de/   A function (dim) that previously returned the number of letters now returns something (1) - wonderful! Everything has to degenerate.

Comment: Ok, I choose instead of dim `\pgfmathparse{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{gas}==0}% new`  for the gas-test. He gives further `0` at gas; it should be `0.09`, after the multiplikation with 1000.

Comment: No, there is nothing "degenerate". The `dim` function only works for arrays. Read the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it was good error wich could be used. Anyway,  please let us stop to discuss that 'dim'.  The test 'is it a gas' can be done by \pgfmathparse{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{gas}==0}. THE ROUNDING of the number does not work here.

Comment: @cis See updated answer.

Comment: Ahh good. ;) .............................

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't use a `pgfmath` function, as you want to return strings and the like, that's not what these functions are made for.

It'll do what you want (I guess):

**Edit:** former version didn't strip the math mode from the results of `\pgfmathprintnumberto`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]
  {
    Z;     Symbol;     Phase;     Density
    1;     H;             gas;          0.0000899
    3;     Li;             solid;        0.53
    118; Og;           unknown;  -1
  }
  {\psetable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cisstrcmp[2]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \edef\tmpa{\detokenize{#1}}%
      \edef\tmpb{\detokenize{#2}}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
\newcommand*\parseDensityShowTest
  {%
    \expandafter\cisstrcmp\expandafter{\Phase}{gas}%
      {%
        \pgfmathparse{1000*\Density}%
        \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed, precision=2]\pgfmathresult\DensityShowTest
      }
      {%
        \pgfmathparse{\Density==-1}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
          \def\DensityShowTest{"?"}%
        \else
          \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed, precision=2]{\Density}\DensityShowTest
        \fi
      }%
    \stripensuremath\DensityShowTest
  }
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\stripensuremath[1]
  {%
    \edef#1%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@secondoftwo#1}%
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\def\Filename{densityshowtest.txt}
\newwrite\MyPSE
\immediate\openout\MyPSE=\Filename

\begin{document}
\foreach \row in {0,...,2}
  {%%
    % In:   
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Z}\of{\psetable}%
    \let\Z\pgfplotsretval
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}%
    \let\Symbol\pgfplotsretval
    %% Phase
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Phase}\of{\psetable}%
    \let\Phase\pgfplotsretval
    % Density Test
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Density}\of{\psetable}%
    \let\Density\pgfplotsretval
    \parseDensityShowTest
    % OUT:
    % This works:
    %\noindent \Z;~~~\Symbol;~~\Density; ~~\Phase; ~~\DensityShowTest \\
    %
    %  Problem here  =======================
    %
    % This works not: ======================
    \immediate\write\MyPSE{\Z; \Symbol; \Density; \Phase; \DensityShowTest}
  }%%
\immediate\closeout\MyPSE

% So this does not work too: 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=true,]{\Filename}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```